# Lint producing warnings for ok being not in capital letters

Tags: android

The app I am developing needs lowercase letter labels for style reasons.

I defined ok like below.

`<string name="ok">ok</string>`

The problem is that Lint is producing warnings for lowercase ok strings.

There is a necessity to resolve Lint warnings for this project. How can I suppress lint warning for this case only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To suppress the warning locally, change to

```
<string name="ok" tools:ignore="Typos">ok</string>
```

or

```
<string name="ok" tools:ignore="Typos,ButtonCase">ok</string>
```

to also suppress another lint warning here.

Add the namespace declaration attribute

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to the root `resources` element if it's not already there.

Comment: I did as you told me but the problem still persists.

Comment: Use "Clear lint markers" to remove old warnings/errors and rerun lint.

Comment: They have disappeared now. Thanks Aalto.

Comment: What to use to suppress a "typo" in a name of the string, such as `<integer name="nist_gov_timeout">5000</integer>` ?

Comment: @Ωmega that looks like another question and not just a followup comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not necessary, it's just a warning.

I prefer OK to Ok but it is a grey area.

(In eclipse)
To remove a lint warning go to project properties -> android lint preferences. Find that warning and disable it